# Pigeonhole principle: Five points on an orange

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Five points are drawn on the surface of an orange. Prove that it is possible to cut the orange in half in such a way that at least four of the points are on the same hemisphere. (Any points lying along the cut count as being on both hemispheres.)

Comment: So how have you been thinking about this? What do you make of the part in brackets?

Comment: Try making your cut so that it goes through 2 of the points.

Comment: Note that, if you were *not* allowed to cut through a point, then placing the five points along a single great circle (assuming a spherical orange here) at equal intervals would give a counterexample. So the parenthetical remark about points lying along the cut is in fact crucial to proving the stated claim.

Comment: This showed up as problem A2 on the 2002 Putnam Competition. ("Given any five points on a sphere, show that some four of them must lie on a closed hemisphere.")

Answer (score 27):

Through any two points, there is a great circle that passes through those two points. Such a cut will split the other 3 pigeons — *oh, I mean points* — among 2 halves.

[You can now handle additional points being on the great circle on your own, I believe.]

Comment: Sure but not every great circle divides the orange into halves, just into 2 pieces of potentially unequal size. Can we always divide it into halves?

Comment: @Tobias A [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) *always* cuts the sphere exactly in half.

Comment: So are oranges spherical? And does it matter? I think convexity is enough to make the solution simple to prove: all you actually need is a cut that divides the orange in half and passes through two specified points on the surface. Whether or not it's a great circle is irrelevant, but if oranges are spherical then as it happens it will be.

Comment: Split the other 3 pigeons! ROFL. (+1) for a great sense of humour (and of course a good answer) :)

Comment: @SteveJessop: While I'm sure there exists some disgustingly non-constructive cut which passes through at least two points and divides the orange evenly, I have to wonder if there is a clean and simple one you can do with an ordinary kitchen knife, given the orange is not exactly spherical and we do want exact halves.

Comment: @Kevin: I was thinking that the two specified points and the centre of mass of the orange describe a plane with the required properties. The orange being convex means we needn't worry about this plane dividing it into more than two connected parts.

Comment: @Kevin: in fact, one can always use an ordinary kitchen knife. Instead of a great circle, one orients the knife to pass through the two points and divide the orange perfectly in half. This is always possible. *Edit*: And Steve Jessop's comment says why.

Comment: @mixedmath - yet it is possible that ALL points are located on the same great circle..

Comment: @johannesvalks: that's fine, because 5 is "at least 4". The question states that points on the cut are in both hemispheres.

Comment: @steve jessop. A point is not divisible, so it cannot be on BOTH hemispheres.

Comment: @johannesvalks: that's not how mathematics works: since the problem clearly defines what a term means (in this case "cut in half"), then that's what it means in this context even if you think it should be given a different name. The so-called "cut" defines two subsets of the orange, whose intersection is not empty, and the question is about points in one or both of those subsets. There might be a better word for that than "cut", but the question is unambiguous.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I agree with you, but I have problem with the term "cut".

Answer (score -1):

Given a sphere with radius $1$.

Use the points

> $$
> A_+(1,0,0), \quad A_-(-1,0,0), \quad B_+(0,1,0), \quad B_-(0,-1,0), \quad C(0,0,1)
> $$

And you **cannot** make such a cut.

As for any great circle, $(A_+,A_-)$ and $(B_+,B_-)$ are never on the same hemisphere.

That is if we exclude points on both hemispheres as being cut through a point.

Comment: If you cut your sphere with the plane defined by $z=0$, then the cut passes through all four of $A_+,A_-,B_+,B_-$, so those four points will each be on *each* of the two hemispheres. One hemisphere will have four points, and the other will have five.